# Leafet - Loading and Instantiating WFS data on Demand

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wfs

I am designing a WebGIS that will give the user the option to load a large range of WFS layers from geoserver. I am keen to avoid the overhead of having to load and instantiate all of these WFS datasets on pageload and would rather only load them when they are toggled on in the layer control.

**Will this potentially avoid downloading MB's of data that may not even get added to the map by the user?**

I figured that If I could attach a function to the layers toggle to either instantiate (if it doesn't already exist) the layer using the WFS feed or remove it from the map depending on whether it is being toggled on or off.

Comment: Layer data is downloaded only for layers that are visible and for the extent of the current view. If layer is not checked in the layer control, no data is downloaded.

Comment: Does this depend how you call the WFS data? For instance i'm using the Leaflet Ajax plugin which states - 'Note that data starts to download when the layer is created NOT when it’s added to the map in order to get a head start.'
If I just did a straight ajax call would that be more suited?

Comment: I was a bit careless with my comment. It is valid only for vanilla Leaflet layers that are loaded from the net by Leaflet itself. That's not he case for `L.geoJSON`, since it expects JSON object for input. If you are loading/getting whole WFS layer at once (wihout bbox) in JSON format, then you have to take care of loading it only when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up doing this. I have a custom checkbox (not in the official Leaflet layer control) that calls a function to load the WFS layer. This saves on the amount of data having to be downloaded on the initial page load, especially if the user never even turns this layer on. There is a variable in the checkbox which I pull in to the toggling function to determine which layer to load. When checking the box and turning the layer on I do some checking to make sure that the layer doesn't already exist. If it does, it skips the WFS call and just adds it to the map.

Note that the geojson layer is instantiated, albeit emptily, before the WFS call. This makes sure stuff like the styling and popup are already set before you add it to the map. Also note that this is using jsonp to avoid cors issues (make sure you have this enabled - i'm using Geoserver so was a simple uncommenting in the web.xml file I think). This works for point, line, polygon etc.

In my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="layerNameforYouToReplace" onclick="layerToggleWFS(this)" />
```

In map.js:

```
var layerNameforYouToReplace = L.geoJson(null, {style: yourStyleFunction
                ,onEachFeature:yourPopup
                });

var geoJsonUrl = 'https://yourserver/geoserver/yourWorkspace/ows';
var wfsParams =
{
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'getFeature',
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
    format_options: 'callback:parseReponse',
    // dataType: 'jsonp',
    srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
}
function layerToggleWFS (box) {
console.log(eval(box.name));
var present = eval(box.name).getLayers().length
console.log(present)
if(box.checked) {
    if (present != 0) {
        console.log((eval(box.name)).getLayers().length)
        map.addLayer(eval(box.name))
        console.log(present)
    } else {
    console.log(present)
    map.addLayer(eval(box.name));
    $.ajax({
        url : geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(wfsParams) + '&typeName=yourWorkspace%3A' + box.name,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'parseReponse',
        success : function handleJson(data) {
        console.log(data)
        eval(box.name).addData(data);
        }
    });
}
} else {
    console.log(box.checked)
    map.removeLayer(eval(box.name));
}

}
```

Hope this helps someone!